Choosing a 2024 educational dev tool for coding once and porting to IOS, Android etc
For learning purposes we want to develop a low-tech software once, and port it to multiple environments. So we're looking for tools / IDE allowing that.
Features: a second-hand shop, items will be added by the users.
Technical must-have: develop once, port to multiple environments: Android, IOS, Windows, a web site. A consistent cross-platform look is acceptable. A DB will be hosted online.
Team skill / experience: this is a self-teaching exercise for a group of students, so a strong community and comprehensive literature are expected.
Timeline: this will be a side-project, with potentially many added functionalities in the future so there is no timeline really. The main thing is to learn some currently needed skill.
Budget: this is a pro bono project so developing/deploying/maintaining it with free tools and the ability to eventually show-case it at a rock-bottom price would be a plus.
Students will use their own Windows computers to work with, some Android phones and some IPhones and Macs to further test the output.
From your experience what framework should we go for? So far our findings:
Xamarin seems good for the purpose (is it ?), but maybe other dev environments are better / simpler to learn & use or with a brighter future on the market?
PhoneGAP is discontinued
Skip looks good but is based on the Apple environment so not our firts choice at this point
Other thoughts?
Thanks for your input, sorry for the long post (and please point to similar, recent threads as must exist, but not found by us yet). We realize this is probably a million-dollar question, but we can only find lists of tools with mismatched pros and cons so of no real help so far.

I would suggest taking a look at Anvil to see if it is suitable for your needs:

Programming Language = Python
IDE = Browser Based nothing to install so should work on just about anything
Apps are Browser Hosted so will work on anything that has a browser = 0 porting effort
DB = Postgres &/or Static File or anything that Python can connect to
Docs & Community - Docs look good & there is a forum + in my experience the support staff are excellent. There are also a set of tutorials.
Your developers will also experience the use of git which is just about essential as well as python & Anvil
Timeline = No problem
Budget = There is a free plan & mention of educational discounts at 100%


Waow thanks Steve this looks like a great tool and environment for our needs.
I see it is noted as being a games dev tool, would this reflect on the result if we aim at developping a more business-like app ? Why would it be restricted to this field ?

@MarsVoyager I am not sure where you saw it notes as such. Like many software environments games is one of the things that  it can be used for - many tools that target educational use use games development as an area of interest as many young developers find that more approachable. Be assured that it is not restricted to games in any way.

If not for HTML, then I would recommend Embarcadero's RAD Studio for C++ or Delphi for OO Pascal.
Or, Lazarus IDE which is also OO Pascal

Free Pascal is a GPL'ed compiler that runs on Linux, Windows, macOS, FreeBSD and others. Free Pascal is designed to be able to understand and compile Delphi syntax, which is OOP. Lazarus is the part of the missing puzzle that will allow you to develop Delphi like programs in all of the above platforms. Unlike Java which strives to be a write once run anywhere, Lazarus and Free Pascal strives for write once compile anywhere. Since the exact same compiler is available on all of the above platforms it means you don't need to do any recoding to produce identical products for different platforms.

As it is, you might want to look at Flutter & Dart and generates apps for Windows, Linux,Mac, Android, iOS and HTML.

thanks for the input, it looks promising, we've got a lot to experiment here. Might take a while before I'm back :-)
